# делаем Floyd`s triangle

Tags: java, циклы

Пример такого треугольника:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

у Меня получилось сделать код, который строит по ***количеству строк*** :

```
public void makeFloyd() {

        int n=15;
        int num= 1;

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(num+" ");
                    num++;
                }
                System.out.println("");

        }
        }
```

Задача: 
Нужно ввести с клавиатуры число, до ***порядкого номера которого*** оно должно продолжаться. Например, для числа 7:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7
```

Comment: if(num == 7) break;

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void makeFloyd() {

    int n=7;
    int num= 1;

        for (int i = 1; num < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(num+" ");
                num++;
                if (num==n) break; 
            }
            System.out.println("");

    }
    }
```

Comment: Вы тестировали? На первый взгляд это не должно работать.